# MS ACCESS Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: ms-access

```
 SELECT t.Padal, u.Nool 
   FROM  (SELECT m.*, @n1:=@n1 + 1 num, 
                 @n2:=IF(Padal = 'பசிப் பிடி உதைத்த ஓமைச் செவ் வரை' , @
                         n1, @n2) pos 
            FROM tbl_padal m, (SELECT @n1:=0, @n2:=0) n 
           ORDER BY m.uqPadalid 
         ) t, tbl_Nool u 
  WHERE t.uqnoolId = u.uqnoolID 
    and u.nool = 'நற்றிணை' 
    and @n2 >= num - 2 
    AND @n2 <= num + 2
```

I want to get above and below two records ( totally five records )

Comment: The error message is correct, that is not valid Access SQL syntax. Please edit your question to explain (in words) what you want the query to return.

Comment: Not that this helps at all, but I don't think Google is translating this properly. 'Omai Tue kicked up like hungry' ?!  (I know, not important, just interesting.  As is the SQL.  If you are only selecting t.Padal and u.Nool- both of which are 'Where' criteria it seems to me you won't be returning anything else.  Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: I am having two tables tbl_padal and tbl_nool the unique id is uqnoolID for both tables i want the column Padal from tbl_padal table and Nool column from tbl_Nool ( in the tbl_padal table i want the padal column the result record plus above and below 2 records from that table ) for example if a am getting result line like "5" it should bring "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" records

Answer (score 0):

@mcbalaji
For an outline, lets build up the sql gradually, from easy and known steps. 
Create and run each of these--

```
1st  SELECT m.* From tbl_padal  m    (note that it is not ordered by uqPadalid)

2nd  SELECT m.* From tbl_padal  m  ORDER By uqPadalid     (now it is ordered)

3rd  SELECT 
     (SELECT Count(*) + 1 FROM tbl_padal AS A WHERE A.uqPadalid < m.uqPadalid ) as RowNum,
     m.*  From tbl_padal  m  ORDER By m.uqPadalid         (now it also has RowNum-s)

4th  So lets pick the central one that we want--
     SELECT RowNum FROM  
       (   SELECT 
           (SELECT Count(*) + 1 FROM tbl_padal AS A WHERE A.uqPadalid < m.uqPadalid ) as RowNum,
           m.Padal,
           m.uqPadalid  From tbl_padal  m  ORDER By m.uqPadalid        
       )
     Where m.Padal = 'your constant' 



Lastly--

SELECT  
  nums.RowNum,
  mm.RowNum,
  mm.Padal,
  mm.uqPadalid
  u.nool

FROM  (
  (   SELECT RowNum, uqPadalid FROM  
       (   SELECT 
           (SELECT Count(*) + 1 FROM tbl_padal AS A WHERE A.uqPadalid < m.uqPadalid ) as RowNum,
           m.Padal,
           m.uqPadalid  From tbl_padal  m  ORDER By m.uqPadalid        
       )
     Where m.Padal = 'constant1' 
  ) as nums

LEFT JOIN

  (   SELECT 
           (SELECT Count(*) + 1 FROM tbl_padal AS A WHERE A.uqPadalid < m.uqPadalid ) as RowNum,
           m.Padal,
           m.uqPadalid  From tbl_padal  m  ORDER By m.uqPadalid  
  ) as mm
   ON                      mm.RowNum  <=   nums.RowNum +2 
    AND nums.Rownum -2 <= mm.RowNum )

LEFT JOIN
   tbl_nool  u
Where mm.uqPadalid = u.uqPadalid
And  u.nool = 'constant2'

Order By  mm.RowNum
```

Comment: gee, which sql and what line is showing what error?  without anything to go on, its a little difficult... tkx